# Frames Not Adhering to Set Size

Tags: width, frame, frameset

Just doing a small PHP assignment in which I am making use of frames to set apart a user interface.

The frames themselves are working fine, however the three columns I have defined as 150,700,200 seem to not stick to the set sizes, and instead opt to take up a portion of the entire screen each.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/QBStyle.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Quality Books</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="180,*", frameborder="no", framespacing="0">
    <frame src="Frames/Header.php" />
    <frameset cols="150,700,200", frameborder="no", framespacing="0">
        <frame src="Frames/Navigation.php"/>
        <frame src="Introduction.php" name="contentframe"/>
        <frame name="sidebar"/>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Your frame widths add up to 1050 pixels. What do you expect to happen if the available width is more than that?

Comment: That's a good point, I think I had a logic lapse somewhere along the line. That's lack of sleep for you.

I guess in a sense that answers my question.